# Replace For-Each loop using Streams

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I want to replace the following for-each loop using Java 8 Streams:

```
for (Rule rule : this.rules) {

    if (rule.getCondition().evaluate(rule, record)) {
        Records.emit(collector, outputStreamMapping.get(rule.getOutputStream()), tuple, recordId, record);
        collector.ack(tuple);

        ruleApplied = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!ruleApplied) {
    LOGGER.warn("No rule was applied to record {}", record);
    LOGGER.debug("Rules: {}", this.rules);
    ErrorReporter.emitErrorNode(this.collector, recordId, componentName,
            "No matching rule for record " + record, record);
    collector.fail(tuple);
}
```

I want to iterate over a set of Rules, and evaluate each Rule's Condition.  If the condition applies, I act on that record and stop processing.  If no Rules are applied, then I want to log that and perform different processing of the record.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this, though.  Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I've tried this:

```
    this.rules.stream().filter(rule -> rule.getCondition().evaluate(rule, record)).forEach((rule) -> {
        Records.emit(collector, outputStreamMapping.get(rule.getOutputStream()), tuple, recordId, record);
        collector.ack(tuple);

        ruleApplied = true;
        break;
    });
```

It doesn't like the break statement, of course, and also complains about `ruleApplied` not being final since it's declared outside the scope of the lambda.

Based on the answers I'm seeing, it seems as though the loop is the cleanest way to do this.  I wasn't sure if there were other stream constructs that would allow me to encapsulate the logic (i.e., the break and the tracking boolean) in a different manner than how I did in the basic loop.

EDIT2:

Here's my solution based on this thread's advice:

```
Optional<Rule> possibleRule = rules.stream().filter(rule -> rule.getCondition().evaluate(rule, record))
        .findFirst();

if (possibleRule.isPresent()) {
    Records.emit(collector, outputStreamMapping.get(possibleRule.get().getOutputStream()), tuple, recordId,
            record);
    collector.ack(tuple);
} else {
    LOGGER.warn("No rule was applied to record {}", record);
    LOGGER.debug("Rules: {}", this.rules);
    ErrorReporter.emitErrorNode(this.collector, recordId, componentName,
            "No matching rule for record " + record, record);
    collector.fail(tuple);
}
```

Comment: The `ruleApplied = true` line in particular is going to be difficult.  The result is not going to be as nice as the code you already have.

Comment: @LouisWasserman agreed. But it's still possible

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Filter, then project with a side-effect, and count the result? Horrible, but it would work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
Optional<Rule> rule = rules.stream().
                       .filter(rule -> rule.getCondition().evaluate(rule, record))
                       .findFirst();
if (rule.isPresent()) {
    Records.emit(collector, outputStreamMapping.get(rule.get().getOutputStream()), 
                 tuple, recordId, record);
    collector.ack(tuple);

    ruleApplied = true;
}
```

Comment: You don't need separate variable ruleApplied. The logic you want to execute if no rule is applied can simply be put inside else block.

Comment: @MrinalK.Samanta Correct, You would need to see how ruleApplied is being used, but the code which checks it might be merged into this `if` or `else` block. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with `Stream`'s `anyMatch` method and a `Predicate` that performs the necessary side effect of `Records.emit`, etc.

```
boolean ruleApplied = this.rules.stream().anyMatch(
    rule ->
    {
        boolean match = rule.getCondition().evaluate(rule, record);
        if (match)
        {
            Records.emit(collector, outputStreamMapping.get(rule.getOutputStream()), tuple, recordId, record);
            collector.ack(tuple);
        }
       return match;
   }
);
```

The [`anyMatch` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) is a short-circuiting operation that will stop processing when the `Predicate` returns `true`.  The short-circuit will fulfill the `break` behavior you have.

> Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided predicate. May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result. If the stream is empty then false is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.
>
> This is a short-circuiting terminal operation.

Comment: this seems like exactly what i want.  i'll try it out and update with my findings.

Comment: @PeterLawrey's solution is much more straightforward and doesn't abuse side effects.  I strongly recommend that solution instead; side effects in `Predicate`s are deeply frowned upon by the documentation.

Comment: reading into docs more, you're right.  for my specific use-case, the coupling of the expression evaluation and the action based on that is not problematic, but the *practice* is.  thanks for the caution